# DbContext.Database.Migrate() doesn't work

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having trouble migrating my SQL Server database in Entity Framework Core 3.1.0 using DbContext.Database.Migrate().

I'm following along in a Udemy course:

https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-entity-framework-core-2-efc2-using-aspnet-core/

In this course, the instructor has the following code:

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private Context _context;

    public HomeController(Context context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public string Index() {
        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        return "DB Created";
    }

    public string Migrate() {
        _context.Database.Migrate();
        return "DB Migrated";
    }
}
```

The Context:

```
public class Context: DbContext {
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options) {

    }

    public DbSet<Author> Author {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Book> Book {get;set;}
}
```

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Author.cs:

```
public class Author {
    public int AuthorId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string MailId {get;set;}

    public ICollection<Book> Books {get;set;}
}
```

Book.cs:

```
public class Book {
    public int BookId {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public int AuthorId {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}

    public Author Author {get;set;}
}
```

When I run this, and go to localhost:5001/Home, it prints out "DB Created" and indeed the database is created with the Author and Book tables in it.

Now I make a few changes. I follow along in the course. The instructor makes the following changes:

Override OnConfiguring(...) in the Context:

```
public class Context: DbContext {
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options) {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(...);
        }
    }

    public DbSet<Author> Author {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Book> Book {get;set;}
}
```

And he changes BuildWebHost(...) in Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

He then adds a new property to the Author model:

```
public class Author {
    public int AuthorId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string MailId {get;set;}
    public string MobileNo {get;set;}

    public ICollection<Book> Books {get;set;}
}
```

He runs the program, goes to localhost:5001/Home/Migrate, and it says "DB Migrated" and indeed the Author table has a new column: MobileNo.

When I do it, however, the new column is not added, and no record exists in __EFMigrationsHistory.

Googling this problem, I find that when you create the DB with EnsureCreated(), no further migrations can be done on it (not sure why). Not sure how the instructor was able to do it.

So I drop the DB and run the program again, this time going directly to localhost:5001/Home/Migrate. It creates the DB with an empty __EFMigrationsHistory and no Author or Book tables.

I read further and find that since EFCore 3.0:

> Also starting in 3.0, the dotnet ef command-line tool is no longer
>   included in the .NET Core SDK. Before you can execute EF Core
>   migration or scaffolding commands, you’ll have to install this package
>   as either a global or local tool. To install the final version of our
>   3.0.0 tool as a global tool, use the following command:
>
> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0

Now I'm not executing migration *commands* but obviously some changes have been made to how migrations work since 2.0, the version used in the course (was it possible to do migrations after creating the DB with EnsureCreated() before 3.0?).

Trying to install the dotnet-ef tool fails saying:

> Package dotnet-ef 3.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2
>   (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2) / any. Package dotnet-ef 3.1.0 supports:
>   netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1) / any

That's where I'm at now. Not sure how to upgrade to netcoreapp3.1 There's instructions online on how to do this for Visual Studio but not Visual Studio Code, the IDE I'm working in.

Some help would be much appreciated, if not for how to upgrade to netcoreapp3.1 then at least how to get DbContext.Database.Migrate() to work (either after running EnsureCreated() or creating the DB with Migrate()).

Comment: Did you try following the [EF Core documentation and tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/install)? (Low) quality issues aside, the course you're looking at is extremely old. EF Core 2 had huge bugs and quirks. We're at EF Core 6 now . The [Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) tutorial shows how to create a new web app, create the model, database, migrations

Comment: EF Core 2 is already out of support and EF Core 3 is also very old. The entire .NET Core 3 wave reaches End-Of-Life in less than a year. The current Long-Term-Support version is .NET (Core) 6, supported until 2024. If you want to learn ASP.NET Core and EF Core, start with the .NET 6 documentation tutorials and `Getting Started` articles. You can get access to *good* courses through the (free) [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/) program. The Pluralsight courses is where some Udemy courses typically steal their content from

Comment: If you think that's an exaggeration [check the Roy Hunt fiasco](https://www.troyhunt.com/the-piracy-paradox-at-udemy/). This has happened multiple times since and Udemy never does anything. If you say "it's free though" consider that your personal data is ending up with "course authors" that don't even bother to include a valid business bio and address in their bio.

Answer (score 0):

If you call _context.Database.Migrate() as the first comment in your context, the OnConfiguring method will not be executed. So, you coud try to execute BEFORE that line:

```html
_ = this.ChangeTracker;
```